# solidity array too long

Tags: solidity

If in solidity code the mapping is too long, I mean mapping address=>int256
If here there are too many addresses Records in this mapping, whether there is a limit for this because if I call this mapping variable it maybe cost too much gas and reach the max? How about this in Tron?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a `mapping` is not the same as an array. A mapping is like a hash table, whereas an array is a list of items with a certain length. From the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/types.html#mapping-types):

> You can think of mappings as hash tables, which are virtually initialised such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose byte-representation is all zeros, a type’s default value.
> [...]
> Because of this, mappings do not have a length or a concept of a key or value being set

A mapping like `mapping (address => int256)` technically contains all addresses, but all of them are set to the default value (0), unless a different value is set. The gas required to read from or write to a mapping does not increase as more items are set.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very clear question. Perhaps this will clear up the confusion.

An array is different from a mapping but deep down it is organized as a mapping where the keys (index) are mapped to the values.

`mapping(address => uint256)` in your example:

There are always 2^256 indexed slots. Since an `address` is a 20-byte value, all the possible indexed values, that is all possible addresses "fit" in all possible 20-byte "slots" which is considerably smaller than all possible 32-byte slots.

Realistically, it will not be economically feasible to fill all possible slots for all possible addresses, so you can proceed on the assumption that it will always work for all addresses your contract and users actually care about.

It costs gas to write non-zero values, as needed. There is no gas cost to initialize the above mapping which will return `0` for uninitialized slots. An array of all possible addresses is not ideal for most practical applications. Use `mapping`.

Hope it helps.